# WebRTC: addicecandidate() vs prepopulating SDP?

Tags: webrtc

In nearly all tutorials on WebRTC, the candidates from the `onicecandidate` callback are sent to the peer via the signalling server prior to `createOffer()`. The peer then adds the candidate via `addicecandidate()`.

However it is also possible to signal the offer/answer with the ice candidates already built in. This can be accomplished by simply waiting for the `null` candidate in the `onicecandidate` callback before creating the offer/answer.

Are there any disadvantages to always sending the candidates via the offer/answer?

Comment: It is done immediately ***after*** `createOffer()`, not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gathering all candidates instead of using trickle ice has severe (several seconds) latency implications. This [webrtchacks post](https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/) is still a good description of the topic.

Comment: Great article. Thanks!